# Можно ли как нибудь получить index полученной записи через модель?

Tags: php, yii2

```
$model = News::find()->where(['category_id'=> $url])->one();
```

Вот я получаю нужную запись из бд, а можно как нибудь получить ее индекс?

Comment: Что подразумевается под словом "индекс"? `$model->id` ?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то $model->id

Comment: Номер записи в таблице, не id

Comment: покажите модель News

Comment: @Houckz а какая задача в целом стоит? Есть мысль, что можно сделать проще, информации по номеру записи в таблице в таком запросе нету

Comment: единственное, что я смог придумать так это бежать foreach до нужной записи и так я получил индекс, думал можно по проще

Comment: Зачем это нужно - вот главный вопрос.

Comment: Так обычно никто не делает, потому что номер записи в талице будет изменятся в зависимости от сортировки и/филтров.